# Oracle XQuery filter and tags

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery

I have a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_AAA_02_2013.dtd">
<edi_l>
<trader cdisp="zzzzzzz">
<idrif idrich="1111111111">
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT111111111111</pod>
  <presa>027292224</presa>
  <cf>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</cf>
  <piva></piva>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
<pos>
  <cau>52</cau>
  <scau>09</scau>
  <codiva>A4</codiva>
  <udm></udm>
  <qta>000000000.0</qta>
  <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
  <impp>000000027.59</impp>
</pos>
</idrif>
<idrif idrich="2222222222">
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT222222222222</pod>
  <presa>027290063</presa>
  <cf>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</cf>
  <piva></piva>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
<pos>
  <cau>52</cau>
  <scau>09</scau>
  <codiva>A4</codiva>
  <udm></udm>
  <qta>000000000.0</qta>
  <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
  <impp>000000027.59</impp>
</pos>
</idrif>
</trader>
</edi_l>
```

If I execute the following:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY 
    ('for $e in //*
     where $e/pod="IT111111111111"
    order by $e
    return $e'
   passing MS386.XML_FILE
 returning content 
 ).getClobVal()
 FROM MS386_XML_TEMPLATE MS386;
```

I do not obtain, in the output, the tags edi_l, trader, ecc.; the file starts from the tag hdr:

```
<hdr>
  <odn>915000591962</odn>
  <pod>IT111111111111</pod>
  <presa>027292224</presa>
  <cf>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</cf>
  <piva/>
  <tdoc>F</tdoc>
  <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
  <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
  <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
  <tcon>0000220</tcon>
  <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
</hdr>
```

Instead, if I execute:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY 
    ('for $e in /*
    where $e//pod="IT111111111111"
    order by $e
    return $e'
   passing MS386.XML_FILE
 returning content 
 ).getClobVal()
 FROM MS386_XML_TEMPLATE MS386;
```

It generates all the tags, but it doesn't filter the pod IT111111111111 (in the file there is also the pod IT222222222222).
How can I generate the xml file with all the tags:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE edi_l SYSTEM "DTD_AAA_02_2013.dtd">
<edi_l>
   <trader cdisp="zzzzzzz">
      <idrif idrich="1111111111">
         <hdr>
            <odn>915000591962</odn>
            <pod>IT111111111111</pod>
            <presa>027292224</presa>
            <cf>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</cf>
            <piva/>
            <tdoc>F</tdoc>
            <dat>07.08.2015</dat>
            <pfra>0000003.3</pfra>
            <pdis>000000003.3</pdis>
            <tcon>0000220</tcon>
            <tf>0000000000027.59</tf>
         </hdr>
         <pos>
            <cau>52</cau>
            <scau>09</scau>
            <codiva>A4</codiva>
            <udm/>
            <qta>000000000.0</qta>
            <pzu>00000.000000</pzu>
            <impp>000000027.59</impp>
         </pos>
      </idrif>
   </trader>
</edi_l>
```

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT XMLQUERY 
    ('copy $e := $doc modify
    delete nodes $e/edi_l/trader/idrif[hdr/pod!="IT111111111111"]
    return $e'
   passing MS386.XML_FILE as "doc"
 returning content 
 ).getClobVal()
 FROM MS386_XML_TEMPLATE MS386;
```

Not needed tags are removed from original xml.
Why author's approach hasn't worked correctly.
1) First for `$e in //*  where $e/pod="IT111111111111"` returns each tag, on each level (remove where and see result). And one of these tag meets the condition. 

2)Secound `for $e in /*  $e//pod="IT111111111111"`. This return whole document becouse condition is true. In document on some level exsits tag "pod" with value ="IT111111111111"

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain what this does, how it's different, and how it solves the original problem?

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers understand this answer even better.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz
thanks for your reply.
Only another question: is there an operator ("WHERE NOT IN" for xml) to filter multiple pods? For example (warning: this is pseudo-code)
delete nodes $e/edi_l/trader/idrif[hdr/pod NOT IN ("IT111111111111", "FR333333333", "DE3233333333")]  
Thanks,
Igor

Comment: `[not(index-of(("IT111111111111","IT222222222222"),hdr/pod))`.Something similar to "not in" operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment to the Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz' s reply; his solution was helpful to solve my problem.
I executed the following query to apply the filter:

```
SELECT XMLQUERY 
    ('copy $e := $doc modify
    delete nodes $e/edi_l/trader/idrif[not(index-of(("IT111111111111","IT222222222222"),hdr/pod))]
    return $e'
   passing MS386.XML_FILE as "doc"
 returning content 
 ).getClobVal()
 FROM MS386_XML_TEMPLATE MS386;
```